# Maven can't compile project even when I can debug it

Tags: java, maven-3, myeclipse

I transferred a big java project to maven and replaced all the libraries used with maven and I can run debug or start just fine meaning that it works normally but for some reason whenever I try to run maven test or install or anything that tries to compile it using maven it fails.

This is my pom file (I use nexus for third party jars):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pbclient2</groupId>
<artifactId>pbclient2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Name</name>
<description>Description</description>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mxmlc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mxmlc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <classifier>mxmlc</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId> <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.9.32</version> <configuration> <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses> 
                </configuration> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal> 
                </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <id>analyze</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build></project>
```

I have tried a lot of plugins and tried deleting the .m2 repository but nothing seems to help.

All the errors I get are

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/worx-pc-01/git/PbClient/pbclient2/src/pb/ui/panels/admin/workorders/configuration/namingConvention/GenericNamingConventionTableModel.java:[10,24] package com.pb.hibernate does not exist

or

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/worx-pc-01/git/PbClient/pbclient2/src/pb/ui/panels/admin/workorders/configuration/namingConvention/GenericNamingConventionTableModel.java:[192,36] cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class PbPwoNamingConfiguration
>     location: class pb.ui.panels.admin.workorders.configuration.namingConvention.GenericNamingConventionTableModel

The package does exist and I don't understand why this won't work like its supposed to.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong since I just started using maven.

Comment: Does package `com.pb.hibernate` exist in your project if not are you sure that the dependency is defined correctly in your pom?

Comment: On which server you are deploying?

Comment: @beresfordt I didn't see that the package it was looking for was in another project because they used to use ant to build it
Put your suggestion to check for the package as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @InsaneCricket answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages suggest to me that either the package `com.pb.hibernate` doesn't exist in your project (maybe it has been renamed and your IDE didn't update every use properly) or it exists in an external dependency which your IDE has somehow got in its path when running/debugging, but the dependency isn't defined correctly in your pom, and so running `mvn clean install` fails